# VideoView freezes for live streams on slow networks

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm using VideoView to play remote videos using HLS
When video is VOD (video on demand - just a remote video file, no live stream) everything works fine.

Problems start when i try to play live streams.
If I'm on the fast network (wifi or 3g/4g) everything works as expected.

If i try to play video over edge network for example, video starts to load, and that's OK.
But if i click back button, whole application just freezes. The weird thing is, that ANR dialog is not shown at all, and the freeze sometimes last more that 20 seconds

Here is the code

```
...
 MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Utility.sanitizeUrl(videoUrl)));
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
        {
            tvError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
    });
    //we also set an setOnPreparedListener in order to know when the video file is ready for playback
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
            {
                // close the progress bar and play the video
                pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //if we have a position on savedInstanceState, the video playback should start from here
                if(savedVideoPosition > 0)videoView.seekTo(savedVideoPosition);

                if (savedVideoPosition == 0)
                {
                    videoView.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    //if we come from a resumed activity, video playback will be paused
                    videoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });
...


@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    videoView.stopPlayback();
}
```

The only thing i could fine in the logs is this
`07-09 10:00:57.665  10499-10499/{package_name_removed} I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 9565 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`